# DataGridView is not showing all columns from table

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, winforms

I have following table in my PostgreSQL database:

```
 Table "public.ads"
        Column        |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |              Default
----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 idad                 | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('ads_idad_seq'::regclass)
 uidowner             | integer                     |           |          |
 month                | integer                     |           |          |
 year                 | integer                     |           |          |
 mileage              | integer                     |           |          |
 idmake               | integer                     |           |          |
 idmodel              | integer                     |           |          |
 idmotor              | integer                     |           |          |
 idbodytype           | integer                     |           |          |
 description          | text                        |           |          |
 createdat            | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 optionalequipmentids | character varying[]         |           |          |
 photos               | character varying[]         |           |          |
 price                | integer                     |           |          |
 generaldata          | jsonb                       |           |          |
 vehicledata          | jsonb                       |           |          |
 engineenvironment    | jsonb                       |           |          |
 conditionmaintenance | jsonb                       |           |          |
 idfueltype           | integer                     |           |          |
Indexes:
    "ads_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (idad)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "ads_idbodytype_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (idbodytype) REFERENCES bodytype(idbodytype) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    "ads_idfueltype_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (idfueltype) REFERENCES fueltype(idfueltype) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    "ads_idmake_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (idmake) REFERENCES make(idmake) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    "ads_idmodel_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (idmodel) REFERENCES model(idmodel) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    "ads_idmotor_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (idmotor) REFERENCES motor(idmotor) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I created method for filling DataGridView with data from table above, and here is the code part:

```
private void FillDataGridAds()
        {
            if (!connected) return;

            string cmdString = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                cmdString = "SELECT * FROM ads";
                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdString, conn);
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridAds.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ex)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText("PostgreSQL exception: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText("Exception ex: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

Designer part of code of my dataGridAds

```
// 
            // dataGridAds
            // 
            this.dataGridAds.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.dataGridAds.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridAds.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;
            this.dataGridAds.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 49);
            this.dataGridAds.Name = "dataGridAds";
            this.dataGridAds.RowHeadersWidth = 51;
            this.dataGridAds.RowTemplate.Height = 29;
            this.dataGridAds.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1326, 549);
            this.dataGridAds.TabIndex = 0;
            this.dataGridAds.CellEndEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridAds_CellEndEdit);
            //
```

Problem:

For some reason when method for filling dataGridAds is triggered, dataGridAds is displaying all columns except `optionalequipmentids` and `photos`, so does anybody know where can be a problem, I was trying to figured out where problem might be, but unsuccessfully, have same issue with another tables in my appplication and want to fix as soon as possible, thank you all in advance.

Comment: You should be aware that when you assign a `DataSource` to a `DataGridView`, then it will display a column for all publicly exposed properties/columns that are basic properties like `int`s, `string`s and `Boolean` etc. values. However, … It will ignore and NOT display any properties that are “collections” or another Class.

Comment: Can you explain better your thoughts ? Here in this case, ads table is public, so if I am right, all columns are friendly public, and in my source I haven't  any properties regarding to these columns , also there is another type for three columns like ```jsonb``` except basic type of data , so I was wondering why DataGridView can show all these columns except character varying[] type of data columns

Comment: I can only guess the grid is looking at those columns as collections. In this case it looks like an array (collection) of `characters`. Can you [edit] your question and show what the `dt` table looks like? I am speculating here as it is not clear what is returned from the DB.

Comment: But I only created new object of DataTable called ```dt``` there in that function, in order to fill ```dt``` within object of NpgSqlDataAdapter called ```da```, and in last step I assigned default view of ```dt```  to ```dataGridAds``` ```DataSource``` and thats all what I have done with DataTable

Comment: I can see that, however, have you checked the `dt` table after it is filled? Does it have the columns in question? And if it does… what “type” are those columns? In addition, is your code adding the columns to the grid or are the columns “auto generated”?

Comment: I checked now, in ```dt``` table there are columns from question and their type value is ```{Name = "Array" FullName = "System.Array"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}``` in runtime when I used debugger, columns are auto generated  I am not adding by code to grid

Comment: Well, that would explain why that column is not displayed. It looks at an array as a collection. The problem for the grid is that it does not know how to add “multiple” items into a “single” cell. If you convert the array to a `string` in the query then it should work.

Comment: @JohnG Thank you a lot !  You explain me to understand a problem in generally, I will try also what Kendle said in the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are both data-type `character varying[]` I assume that the columns in other tables with the same problem are the same data-type.
You could try using `CAST`. Does the following script with a nomnative SELECT with CASE for the problem columns work?
If `CAST( ... AS VARCHAR(1000))` doesn't work you could also try
`CAST( ... AS VARCHAR)`

```
private void FillDataGridAds()
        {
            if (!connected) return;

            string cmdString = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                cmdString = 
"SELECT 
 idad                 ,
 uidowner             ,
 month                ,
 year                 ,
 mileage              ,
 idmake               ,
 idmodel              ,
 idmotor              ,
 idbodytype           ,
 description          ,
 createdat            ,
CAST( optionalequipmentids AS VARCHAR(1000)),
CAST( photos             AS VARCHAR(1000)),
 price                ,
 generaldata          ,
 vehicledata          ,
 engineenvironment    ,
 conditionmaintenance ,
 idfueltype FROM ads";

                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(cmdString, conn);
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridAds.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ex)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText("PostgreSQL exception: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText("Exception ex: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have tried this one now, but nothing happens when I clicked on button reload , which has triggering this function, I also used debugger to check line by line, and value of cmdString variable is null from run state of application

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I made typo mistake and that's the reason why this was not working, so I will mark this as answer

Comment: Glad it worked. Does it load the problem columns correctly?

Comment: Yes, it loaded columns correctly.